# Consume a String sent via PUT method

Tags: java, rest, put

I'm developing REST services using Jersey. In a PUT method, I want to consume a String, and then use it in another method.

Something like: I enter a String in the "Content" field (of TEST REST WEB SERVICES page) and then I use that String in a **logout** method:

```
@PUT
@Path("logout")
@Produces({"application/json", "text/plain"})
@Consumes(**xxxxx**)
public String logout(**xxxxx**) throws Exception
{
     String reponse = null;
     reponse = new UserManager().logout(**xxxxx**);
     return reponse;
}
```

So, I want to know what to put in the ** xxxxx ** fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a String argument. The JAX-RS runtime will marshall the request body into it.

```
@PUT
@Path("logout")
@Produces({"application/json", "text/plain"})
public String logout(String data) throws Exception {
     String response = null;
     reponse = new UserManager().logout(data);
     return response;
}
```

You should define `@Consumes` to be whatever content type(s) you want to allow the client to be able to send, or leave it out altogether to accept any content type.

Comment: Great, feel free to either accept this answer, if it helped you. Good luck with the rest of the project.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I needed some kind of annotation.

Comment: And if I want to enter more than one parameter, do you know how can I separate them in the "Content" field?

Comment: The request body can only be marshaled once. And request body != request parameter (not sure if you are mixing up the two). If you are sending over multipart/form data then you can get each parameter via a `@FormParam("paramName")` annotation.